# How to configure Cloud SQL Postgres to require SSL but not client certificates?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to create a Cloud SQL Postgres instance that [Enforces SSL/TLS](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance#enforcing-ssl), but that does not require the use of client certificates? In [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), this would be a line containing `hostssl` but *not* `clientcert=1`.

I have tried [Enforcing SSL/TLS](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance#enforcing-ssl) (`settings.ipConfiguration.requireSsl` on the instance, or `gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --require-ssl`) But this option seems pretty useless, because:

1. According to [Managing your client certificates](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ssl-instance#client-certs)
   , you can only create “up to 10 client certificates for each instance.” This means that we would have to share the same client certificate/private keys among multiple users or services, so the secret is not truly secret among our employees.
2. After presenting a client `sslkey`/`sslcert` in `psql`, postgres still asks for a password. This is evidence that the Cloud SQL `sslCerts` API inserts a `clientcert=1` auth-option, as opposed to a `cert` auth-method, into [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). This means that each client needs *both* a client cert *and* a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud SQL always requires client SSL certificate when configured with option: [Allow only SSL connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance#enforcing-ssl). There is also no access to pg_hba.conf file to change auth-method to cert for Cloud SQL.

As a workaround you can create [PostrgreSQL on Compute engine using this Google Cloud Marketplace link](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?q=postrgresql), where you will have access to auth-method in pg_hba.conf